# How to compare two arrays in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

how can i return buttons with backgroundColor if lines's array's element equals to map index ?
this only works for if lines = [0,1,2] ,

```
let lines=[0,6,9]
 return (
        <div>
            {new Array(9).fill(null).map((e, i) => {
                let color='green';
                if(lines[i] === i) {
                return (
                        <React.Fragment key={i}>
                        <button style={{backgroundColor:this.props.color}}>MyButton {i}<button/>
                        {(i+1) % props.width === 0 && <br />}
                       </React.Fragment>
                      )
                }

                return(

                    <React.Fragment key={i}>
                        <button>MyButton {i}<button/>
                        {(i+1) % props.width === 0 && <br />}
                    </React.Fragment>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the condition from

```
if(lines[i] === i)
```

to

```
lines.includes(i)
```

Also you need not repeat the same code again instead, you can add the styles based on the condition's result like below.

```
let lines=[0,6,9]
   return (
    <div>
      {new Array(9).fill(null).map((e, i) => {
        let color = "green";
        let styles = {};
        if (lines.includes(i)) {
          styles = { backgroundColor: this.props.color };
        }
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={i}>
            <button type="button" styles={styles}>
              MyButton {i}
            </button>
            {(i + 1) % props.width === 0 && <br />}
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if(lines[i] === i)
```

you can just do

```
if (lines.find(lineArrayItem => lineArrayItem === i))
```

this code just try to find out if i is present in lineArrayItem . if Not it returns null so that way you can know if the index matches with any item of lines array or not.